# Centrar varias vistas en un contenedor con SWIFTUI

Tags: swift

estoy empezando a utilizar SWIFTUI y me estoy encontrando con algún problema a la hora de querer centrar varias vistas dentro de un contenedor.

Mi intención es llegar a tener los campos con valor 1,2,3 y 4 centrados con respecto al contenedor:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado utilizar la siguiente opción seleccionando las 4 vistas antes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero queda todo apelotonado de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto no es SwiftUI es UIKit

Answer (score 0):

Intenta lo siguiente:

Tus 4 labels (1, 2, 3, 4) ponlos en un StackView horizontal
Tus otros 4 textfields igual en otro StackView horizontal

Seleccionas ambos StackViews y los metes dentro de un StackView Vertical.

Ahora a ese stack vertical, asigna un constraint top y marca la casilla Horizontally in Container.

---

Los stacks horizontales puedes seleccionar que se llenen proporcionalmente en el inspector, de esta manera harán match cada label con cada textfield.

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Un ejemplo de cómo podrías montarlo:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var code1: String = ""
    @State var code2: String = ""
    @State var code3: String = ""
    @State var code4: String = ""

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
            
            Text("Please, enter the authentication code")
                .padding(.bottom, 10)
            
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("1")
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                Text("2")
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                Text("3")
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                Text("4")
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                Spacer()
            }
            
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                TextField("", text: self.$code1)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(TextAlignment.center)
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke())
                TextField("", text: self.$code2)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(TextAlignment.center)
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke())
                TextField("", text: self.$code3)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(TextAlignment.center)
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke())
                TextField("", text: self.$code4)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(TextAlignment.center)
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke())
                Spacer()
            }
            
            HStack {
                Text("Back")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                Spacer()
                Text("Next")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Así quedaría en el simulador...]